# Acyclic visitor pattern. Moving the accept function to just one place

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Below I've taken out the `accept (const ChooseVisitor&);` function out of `Object` and placed it in `Menu<T>::Option` instead so that it would only need to be called there instead of the many classes that will have the `accept` function.  The only problem is that `T` may be a pointer or a reference, or whatever, and I need to turn into into a regular type without pointer or reference or const, etc... to get `T::Visitor*` to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 

struct ChooseVisitor {
    virtual ~ChooseVisitor() = default;
};

struct Object {
    struct Visitor {
        virtual void visit (Object*) const = 0;
    };
//   void accept (const ChooseVisitor&);  // I've decided to move this into Menu instead (to avoid the repetitions in other classes).
};

struct PurchaseObjectVisitor : public ChooseVisitor, public Object::Visitor {
    virtual void visit (Object* object) const {
        std::cout << object << " purchased.\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Menu {
    struct Option {
        T item;
        template <typename> void accept (const ChooseVisitor&);
    };
    Option* option;  // Assume Menu<T> with only one option for simplicity here.
    template <typename> void choose() const;
    void insert (const T& t) {option = new Option{t};}
};

template <typename T>
template <typename Visitor>
void Menu<T>::Option::accept (const ChooseVisitor& visitor) {
//  using Type = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type;  // How to cover all possible cases?
    const typename Type::Visitor* v = dynamic_cast<const typename Type::Visitor*> (&visitor);
    if (v) v->visit(item);
}

template <typename T>
template <typename Visitor>
void Menu<T>::choose() const {
    const Visitor visitor;
    option->template accept<Visitor>(visitor);  // template disambiguator needed.
}

int main() {
    Menu<Object*> menu;
    menu.insert (new Object);
    menu.choose<PurchaseObjectVisitor>();
}
```

I'm starting with

```
template <typename T>
struct GetVisitor {
    using type = std::is_pointer<T>::value ? typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type::Visitor : typename T::Visitor;
};
```

but it is not working right now, and also it needs to handle ALL the possible types.  What's the most elegant way to do this?  Is there a simple function that does that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `::type`. It should be  `std::remove_pointer<T>::type`

**Update:** To get plain type you can nest the `std::remove_` templates - `std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<typename std:: remove_reference<T>::type>::type>::type`

Comment: I found that out just now, but I still need to generalize to all other possible removals.  I've updated my question.  Oh, and I believe you know where my question is coming from gmbeard (from my last question).  I'm still following your idea, but because different actions will occur based on where the menu is being used, I need to pass different Visitor types into the choose() function, in order to supply different overrides for the same type T for different situations.

Comment: Yeah, your other question is definitely a challenge. You're delving into the murky waters of static heterogenous containers. A variant/visitor pattern seems the only way.